# Why can't I assign Predicate<T> to a Predicate<object> when T is descended from object?

Tags: c#, delegates

Title says all. If I have, say, a field

```
private Predicate<object> myPredicate;
```

why can't I assign a

```
Predicate<T>
```

instance to that field?

Comment: co and contravariance i think

Comment: `Predicate<in T>` implements contravariance.

Comment: Because otherwise you'd be able to call your T predicate with something that is not a T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [`Predicate<in T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bfcke1bz.aspx) implements contravariance. So you can

```
Predicate<string> predString;
Predicate<object> predObject = (object x) => x != null;
predString = predObject;
```

but not the opposite.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

If you think a second on it, it is logical... In the example I gave,

```
bool result = predString("Foo");
```

`"Foo"` is a valid parameter (a `string`) for `predObject` (that accepts an `object`).

The opposite wouldn't be ok:

**illegal code**

```
Predicate<object> predObject;
Predicate<string> predString = (string x) => x.Length != 0;
predObject = predString;
```

and then

```
bool result = predObject(new object());
```

Clearly `new object()` is an illegal parameter for `predString` (that requires a `string` parameter)!